# Symfony 3 - Add debug on each view render

Tags: symfony, view, overriding

I develop on a big new website some features.
There is lot of views and it's difficult to understand where the code is executed. I would like to add html comments on each render view of this website to help all developer to see where there are i try with kernel view but this listener is never lauch

If you known how i can do please ?

thx by advance

Comment: `APP_ENV=dev` in `.env` file helps a lot.

Comment: Thx for your answer but i want to see quicky what view is render thanks to html comments

Comment: Well, add that comment in the views

Comment: Yes but i dont want to pass in all views to add my comment, for exemple i want this : <!-- render view user/list_order/index.html.twig --!> on the top of each view dynamicly to see when i'm in the website in the DOM what view is render, you see what i mean ?

Comment: If you don't want to manually open each file, write a script that will loop over the views folder and add the comment top of those files

Comment: By the way, using the `_profiler` will let you to quickly (2 clicks) see what template is rendered and the hierarchy of those.

Comment: Yep i see what you say, but i find a way with Override / Listener the default render of a view to put it in a class and it will be ok.

Comment: i see but this project is really in disorder i see the _profiler but i cant see where i am realy with it

Comment: When you're on a page and open the profiler with the toolbar, the profiler is corresponding to that page.

Answer (score 0):

With your Symfony 3 app use http://localhost/app_dev.php/

When you call that URL Symfony will load the tool bar at the bottom that will provide the details you are looking for.

With Symfony 4 this is controlled by your environment settings.

[image]